# Salesforce Opportunity Validation from Custom button

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I have a custom button "Submit Order" which simple change Opportunity Stage.

But i want to add some validation check before changing Stage

Here is my apex class

```
global class SubmitOrder {

public SubmitOrder(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
{
}

Webservice static string Submit(string oppId)
{
    string message = '';
    try
    {
        List<Opportunity> listOpp = new List<Opportunity>();
        Opportunity oppNew = [SELECT id, StageName, Destination_Zone__c, Sold__c  FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :oppId];

        boolean flag = true;
        if(oppNew.StageName!= 'To Be Searched' && oppNew.StageName != 'Search')
        {
            oppNew.StageName.addError('Stage should be \'To Be Searched\' or \'Presentation\' or \'Search');
            flag = false;
        }
        if( oppNew.Destination_Zone__c == '')
        {
            oppNew.Destination_Zone__c.addError('Destination Zone is required');
            flag = false;
        }
        if(oppNew.Sold__c < 0)
        {
            oppNew.Sold__c.addError('Sold is required');
            flag = false;
        }

        if(flag)
        {
            oppNew.StageName = 'Ticketing';
            listOpp.add(oppNew);
            if (listOpp != null && !listOpp .isEmpty())
            {
               Database.update(listOpp);
            }
            message ='Saved Successfully';
    }
    catch(System.CalloutException e)
    {
        message = e.getMessage();
    }
    return message;
}
}
```

And call for custom button is

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/10.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/10.0/apex.js")}

var oppId= "{!Opportunity.Id}";
var result = sforce.apex.execute("SubmitOrder","Submit",{oppId:oppId });
```

but getting following error

**SObject row does not allow errors**

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are taking the ID and passing that to a method which retrieves the OLD row with that ID that is already in the database, and trying to use addError() on that. It won't work because addError() will not work on rows that are already in the database.

Without knowing your exact requirements I would make this suggestion - put validation rules on the Opportunity object. Then you can code your button to just simply update the record. The validation rules will take care of the rest.

Comment: naomi, if take a new Opportunity object and add validations to that object then how it will update old record?

Comment: What I mean is this. Go to YourName->Setup->Customise->Opportunities->ValidationRules and create some validation rules. That will stop updates from going ahead unless the update is in accordance with the rules. Then all your button needs to do is a plain update, and the validation rules will take care of whether that update is allowed to actually happen or not.

Comment: If i add validation rules then those will apply to standard button "Save" as well, i want validation on custom button only

Comment: OK. Then what you are doing in the code above is pretty much correct - setting the flag to false on error and then only updating the record if the flag is true. The only problem is that you are trying to use the addError() function. You will need to find another way of alerting the user to the fact there is an error. Possibly a Javascript alert?

Comment: namoi, i did same used Javascript alert, but there are large number of values and difficult to find after Javascript alert, so its better to show error next to each field, thanks anyway